# YouTube Data API OAuth 2.0 - response scope parameter throws 403

Tags: api, redirect, oauth-2.0, scope, youtube

I'm requesting an OAuth code for YouTube authorization / refresh tokens.  My request is valid and so is YouTube's API response; HOWEVER, their response includes a 'scope' argument at the end that throws a 403.  Since they want a full URL as the scope parameter and they pass it back in the redirect as a full URL, it throws a 403 and I cannot extract the code parameter from the URL.  Example redirect from their own docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps):

```
...oauth2callback?state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&code=4/tQEJXSR8oWUlGNinu2ewAaCxEKknh_2zTm9g9Wa-mIPJK85mkaipYczZR35_t2XfqP806TspR0FLUFcIQ4sb_-Q&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
```

YouTube controls the redirect URL, and their addition of this scope argument at the end causes a 403.  Remove the scope argument, it works perfectly.  Anyone know a workaround for this / am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

For anyone running into this, security settings on our server were blocking any requests containing args starting with 'http/s://' See rules related to remote file injection in your security settings.